# CSS background image for fluid layouts

Tags: ipad, html, css

I am trying to apply a background-image to a li element.

```
<ul>
<li class="maintablink">&nbsp;</li>
</ul>
```

My CSS for the same is

```
li.maintablink{background:url(../images/tab_content.png) no-repeat left top;}
```

**Even adding some width:200px;height:200px above does not work.**

I am using HTML5 doctype

I have 2 questions related to this;

1. The background image is slightly bigger and does not display fully inside the li. i.e. it indirectly depends on the content inside my li element. I do not want to give any content inside li (except `&nbsp;`)
   How do I fix this issue ?
2. I am using fluid layout (everything in %, no px value)...So how do I give the width/height for this background-image...It should scale with the browser size (I know for page images, we use `img{max-width:100%}`)...But how do I make background-images scalable ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for the CSS `background-size` property.

For a background that is scalable according to the size of the container:

```
background-size: auto;
```

For a background that is a fixed size, regardless of the size of the container or the actual background image:

```
background-size: 150px 200px;
```

You can also use percentages, or the keywords `contain` or `cover`.

See http://www.css3.info/preview/background-size/ for more info.

Please note that `background-size` does have quite good browser support now, but some older browsers (in particular IE8 and earlier, but also Firefox 3.x) do not support it.

If you need to support these browsers fully, you will need to work out a fall-back solution (probably using additional markup and/or Modernizr to determine whether the feature is available).

Comment: Thx a lot...So when we say background-size: auto; does it take as per the background-image's own width/height OR the width/height we give to that element itself OR to it's containing element ?

Answer (score -1):

Apply a background-image to a li element

> ***li*** is not a block element so you must be change `display:inline-block` before you set width and height.

There is an option to set ***background-size*** in ***CSS*** you can follow this [link](http://www.css3.info/preview/background-size/),. If you don't want to show your content from ***li*** element just put the `text-indent:-9999px` to you ***li*** css.

Check out this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RuRWS/) for testing `background-size`

Comment: I just tried adding display:inline-block;width:300px;height:300px;background:url(../images/tab_content.png) no-repeat left top;background-size:auto; to my li element CSS...But still does not work..

Comment: Thx...In your jsfiddle demo, if I remove, the fixed px width/height, it does not work...and that is what i am looking for...no px dimensions..only relative like % dimensions..